# How can I get the result of an stored procedure from Symfony

Tags: symfony, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to execute this stored procedure on SQL Server 2012 from Symfony,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_cumplerequisito @param integer
AS
IF (select count(*) from [dbo].[cumplerequisito]
where estado=1 and inscripcion_id=@param) = (select count(*) from [dbo].[requisito]
where estado=1)
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0;
GO
```

I need the return value of the stored procedure, so I tried this from Symfony:

```
 $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery('EXEC sp_cumplerequisito 1', $rsm);
    $query->setParameter('param', 1);
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

then I tried to use this code in order to use the $result value,

```
if ($result ==1){          
         $mensaje = 'Estudiante  ha cumplido todos los requisitos';
          return $this->render('academicoBundle:Default:estudiantematriculado.html.twig', array('mensaje' => $mensaje));
              }else{
         $mensaje2 = 'Estudiante no ha cumplido todos los requisitos';
         return $this->render('academicoBundle:Default:estudiantematriculado.html.twig', array('mensaje' => $mensaje2));}
```

but I have this response "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. "

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To honest You shouldent do procedure in Your databases. `Doctrine ORM` is build to omit such things and move things from DB to PHP. So if for example You want to increment field after update/insert You have to use `doctrine lifecycle callbacks`, So You should move this procedur to Your `repository class`

Comment: Thanks, I did move the procedure to the repository and it worked.